# Why would ImageMagick & Ghostscript work in CMD but not in PHP?

Tags: iis, imagemagick, ghostscript, windows-server-2019, php-7.4

We are migrating from a Windows 2012 Server to a Windows 2019 server. We have been using ImageMagick as Imagick in PHP and Ghostscript to convert PDF files into JPG files for quite some time without issue, but now on the new server it will not work. This is the error message we receive:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gs" -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r300x300" -dPrinted=false -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 "-sOutputFile=C:/Windows/TEMP/magick-mkMmFi8vXckWEAzjPQWNNyAeLCmErcUI%d" "-fC:/Windows/TEMP/magick-RHvJ0K3gv-gkEMBSrS8cft5IBz4k5e3f" "-fC:/Windows/TEMP/magick-YHH7fNU9o9vL3dni8YuaJxpvgDWi04hK"' (The system cannot find the file specified. ) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/516 in C:\inetpub\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\crons\test.php:1214 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\crons\test.php(1214): Imagick->readImage() #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\crons\test.php on line 1214

We have ImageMagick 7.1.0 installed, Ghostscript 10, and the PHP extension added for Imagick along with the necessary files.

Here is what we have already tried...

1. ImageMagick and Ghostscript paths are both in the Environmental Variables.
2. Modified the Delegates.xml for ImageMagick with full path to Ghostscript.
3. Modified the Policy.xml for ImageMagick to uncomment PDF domain module, including adding "read|write", as well as uncommenting the temporary-path line.
4. Verified the Ghostscript registery keys exist and point to the correct paths.
5. Verified all directories had the necessary permissions.

As well as probably some other things we are just forgetting. None of those steps were necessary on the old server.

It DOES work as expected when run from command line as

```
magick test.pdf test.png
```

But it will not work when run from PHP.

At this point we are completely stumped. We have been searching and trying suggestions for hours, but nothing seems to work. If anyone has gotten this working and we are just missing something, advice would be so greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention we are running PHP 7.4.3 and everything is 64bit (Windows, IIS, PHP, ImageMagick, Ghostscript).

We can also use `exec("gswin64c --help", $array);` in PHP to display info about Ghostscript with no errors. So the issue is just that the PHP imagick extension can't seem to access Ghostscript.

Comment: "in the Environmental Variables", then in the local environment or in the system environment? You can refer to `setx` documentation to see how people usually configure the system environment, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx You also need to reset IIS so that changes to the system environment can take effect.

Comment: PHP and Imagemagick command line get data from different ENV variables.

Comment: When I use `$path = getenv('PATH');` in PHP it shows both ImageMagick and Ghostscript, so the ENV variables seem to be set correctly.

Comment: We just changed all code to use wkhtmltoimage instead of Imagick and Ghostscript. Would be nice to know what the issue was with what has worked for us for years, but found a suitable alternative.

Comment: I 'fixed' this same problem, except using x86 and PHP 7.2. The Imagick PHP module appears to be expecting your system to know what to do with a 'gs' command, and I suspect that this reference is baked in to the binaries I downloaded for my system (I could not find an installation tip or setting to make Imagick look for a different binary). Maybe compiling my own binaries would solve this? I ended up just copying the ghostscript binary to a new file name in the same directory `gs.exe` instead of `gswin32.exe`, so now I have both sitting there side by side and Imagick works properly.